# Change color of Sticky text when its active

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was looking at nice timeline script and wanted to use, i made several change to css as per my design but I was wondering if i could change the color of active year from gray to red when page is being scrolled,

I looked at the code and found that when page is scrolled no class is changed to relect sticky behaviour of the active year.

```
#timeline h3 {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 5rem;
  color: #888;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Can we change color of active year when page is being scrolled/

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:200,400,500);
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #79838c;
}

a {
  color: #50585f;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #383e44;
}

div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100%;
}

div.header {
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: slategrey;
  color: ghostwhite;
  padding: 2.3rem 1rem 2.3rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
div.header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5rem;
  left: 0rem;
  height: 5.1rem;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 );
  /* IE6-9 */
}
div.header h1 {
  margin-top: .8rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  div.header h1 {
    font-size: 1.9em;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  }
}
div.header h2 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #cfd7de;
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: auto;
}

div.item {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0rem 1rem 0rem 1rem;

}

#timeline {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5rem;

}
#timeline div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: .5rem;
  bottom: 0rem;
  left: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #C5C5C5;
}
#timeline h3 {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 5rem;
  color: #888;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  #timeline h3 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
}
#timeline section.year {
  position: relative;
}
#timeline section.year:first-child section {
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#timeline section.year section {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 2.2em;
}
#timeline section.year section h4 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 89px;
  color: #C5C5C5;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  #timeline section.year section h4 {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
#timeline section.year section ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 75px;
  margin: -1.35rem 0 1em;
  max-width: 32rem;
  font-size: 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  #timeline section.year section ul {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 0 0 0 81px;
  }
}
#timeline section.year section ul:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#timeline section.year section ul:first-of-type:after {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #C5C5C5;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 54px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#timeline section.year section ul li {
  margin-left: .5rem;
}
#timeline section.year section ul li:before {
  content: '·';
  margin-left: -.5rem;
  padding-right: .3rem;
}
#timeline section.year section ul li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: .5rem;
}
#timeline section.year section ul li span.price {
  color: mediumturquoise;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#price {
  display: inline;
}

svg {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bitcoin timeline with fixed header using flexbox</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->

<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <div id="timeline">
      <div>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2007</h3>
          <section>
            <ul>
              <li>Satoshi Nakamoto began working on the Bitcoin concept.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>     
        </section>
  
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2008</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Neal Kin, Vladimir Oksman, and Charles Bry file an application for an encryption patent application.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin.org was registered at <a href="https://anonymousspeech.com/">anonymousspeech.com</a>.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
    
          <section>
            <h4>October</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Nakamoto describes the Bitcoin currency and solves the problem of double spending.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
    
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>The Bitcoin project is registered on <a href="https://sourceforge.net/">SourceForge.net</a>.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
  
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2009</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Block 0 is established.</li>
              <li>Version 0.1 of Bitcoin is released.</li>
              <li>The first Bitcoin transaction.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>October</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>An exchange rate is established.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.2 is released.</li>
              <li>The difficulty increases.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
  
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2010</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>The Bitcoin Market is established as a Bitcoin currency exchange.</li>
              <li>Encryption patent is published.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>May</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>The first real-world transaction using 10,000 BTC spent on pizza.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>July</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.3 released.</li>
              <li>In five days, the price grew 1000%, rising from <span class="price">$0.008</span> to  <span class="price">$0.08</span> for 1 bitcoin.</li>
              <li>The MtGox Bitcoin currency exchange market is established.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Exploit generates 184 billion Bitcoins.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>October</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Financial task force issues warning.</li>
              <li>The first public version of an OpenCL miner is released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Market cap exceeds $1 million USD.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoind compiled for Nokia N900.</li>
              <li>First mobile Bitcoin transaction.</li>
              <li>Difficulty increases.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2011</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Silk Road opens for business.</li>
              <li>25% of total Bitcoins generated.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin reaches parity with US dollar.</li>
              <li><a href="https://weusecoins.com/">WeUseCoins.com</a> is created.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Second largest decrease in difficulty.</li>
              <li>Britcoin opens for trading.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin Brasil opens.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>April</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin passes parity with Euro.</li>
              <li>Difficulty surpasses 100,000.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>June</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin Market drops PayPal.</li>
              <li>The largest percentage price decrease to-date became known as the Great Bubble of 2011. Top of bubble at <span class="price">$31.</span></li>
              <li>WikiLeaks starts accepting Bitcoin.</li>
              <li>Major breach of security at MtGox.</li>
              <li>Difficulty passes 1 million.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin Conference and World Expo in New York City, NY.</li>
              <li>P2Pool mines its first block.</li>
              <li>Back-to-back drop in difficulty.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>September</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Casascius coins mint physical Bitcoins.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin & Future Technology European Conference in Prague, Czech Republic.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><span class="price">$2</span> minimum price after the first price drop.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2012</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>September</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>London 2012 Bitcoin Conference.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin Foundation begins.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Slowly rising for a year. Price at <span class="price">$13.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2013</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.8 released.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin goes up to <span class="price">$30.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin spikes to $74.90.</li>
              <li>Market cap reaches $1 billion.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>April</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin surpasses <span class="price">$100.</span></li>
              <li>Price hits an all-time high of <span class="price">$266.</span></li>
              <li>Bitcoin Central is hacked.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>May</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>First Bitcoin ATM unveiled.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin Central gets hacked again.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>October</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>FBI shuts down Silk Road.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin price drops from <span class="price">$139</span> to <span class="price">$109.71</span> in less than three hours after Silk Road closure, recovers.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin price surges to a new all-time record of <span class="price">$1242.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Price crashed to <span class="price">$600</span>, rebounded to <span class="price">$1000</span>, crashed again to the <span class="price">$500</span> range. Stabilized in between.</li>
              <li>China's Central Bank bans Bitcoin transactions.</li>
              <li>The network exceeded 10 petahash/sec.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2014</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Price spiked to <span class="price">$1000</span>, then settled in the <span class="price">$800–$900</span>range.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.9 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>June</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>The network exceeded 100 petahash/sec.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Microsoft began to accept bitcoin to buy Xbox games and Windows apps.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2015</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.10 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>July</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.11 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>2015 record high of <span class="price">$504.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2016</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Price at <span class="price">$1150</span> per bitcoin.</li>
              <li>Price fell 30% in a week, reaching a multi-month low of <span class="price">$750.</span></li>
              <li>The network exceeded 1 exahash/sec.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.12 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>April</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Steam started accepting bitcoin as payment.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.13 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>September</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>There are 770 bitcoin ATMs worldwide.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2017</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.14 released.</li>
              <li>The price of 1 bitcoin surpassed the spot price of an ounce of gold for the first time.</li>
              <li>The number of GitHub projects related to bitcoin passed 10,000.</li>
              <li>Price traded above <span class="price">$1290.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>April</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Japan Declares Bitcoin as Legel Tender</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin "splits" into Bitcoin (BTC) and Bitcoin Cash (BCH)</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin for the first time hit <span class="price">$10,000</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2019</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>Today</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>At the moment, one bitcoin cost:
                <span class="price">
                  <div id="price"></div>.
                </span>
               </li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script >
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add active class using jQuery or javascript to the element on scroll then on the base of active class add css to change its color.

Comment: That is my question how can i target it when i dont know from css which element is active as while debugging i can't find any change in CSS side when i scroll the page..

Comment: There is no active class added on scroll to year element so that what i am saying add an active class yourself by script then on the basic of that active class change color

Comment: and how will you target active element? for year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK here is an idea hope you can make it work

- Define a method `isInViewport` to check if the element is in the viewport
- Define a method `markActive` to query all year elements remove previous active classes and loop through to find out the first element in viewport mark it as active
- Add an eventListener on your scrolling container to listen for scroll call a method to mark `markActive` the active year in your timeline. debounce it so we do not do a lot of processing on main thread.
- Add the `markActive` method to `window.onload` for marking the active year in the timeline when page loads

```
window.onload = markActive;
container.addEventListener('scroll', function (e){
  setTimeout(markActive, 0) 
});

function markActive() {
  activeYear.classList.remove('active');
  //const timelines = document.querySelectorAll('section.year > h3');  //es6
  var timelines = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('section.year > h3'));//ES5
  for(let i=0; i<timelines.length; i++) {
    if(isInViewport(timelines[i])) {
      timelines[i].classList.add('active');
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

**attached in the snippet below ...**

```js
window.onload = markActive; // when page loads
var debounce = 0;
document.querySelector('.item').addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  if(debounce){
    clearTimeout(debounce);
  }
  debounce = setTimeout(markActive, 0);
});



function markActive() {
  var activeYear = document.querySelector('.active');
  if(activeYear){
    activeYear.classList.remove('active');
  }
  // work on a detached list
  //const timelines = document.querySelectorAll('section.year > h3');  //es6 
  var timelines = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('section.year > h3'));//ES5
  for(var i=0; i<timelines.length; i++) {
    if(isInViewport(timelines[i])) {
      timelines[i].classList.add('active');
      break;
    }
  }
}

function isInViewport(elem) {
  var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    bounding.top >= 0 &&
    bounding.left >= 0 &&
    bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
    bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
  );
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:200,400,500);
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #79838c;
}

a {
  color: #50585f;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #383e44;
}

div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100%;
}

div.header {
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: slategrey;
  color: ghostwhite;
  padding: 2.3rem 1rem 2.3rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
div.header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5rem;
  left: 0rem;
  height: 5.1rem;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 );
  /* IE6-9 */
}
div.header h1 {
  margin-top: .8rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  div.header h1 {
    font-size: 1.9em;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  }
}
div.header h2 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #cfd7de;
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: auto;
}

div.item {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0rem 1rem 0rem 1rem;

}

#timeline {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5rem;

}
#timeline div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: .5rem;
  bottom: 0rem;
  left: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #C5C5C5;
}
#timeline h3 {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 5rem;
  color: #888;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#timeline h3.active {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  #timeline h3 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
}
#timeline section.year {
  position: relative;
}
#timeline section.year:first-child section {
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#timeline section.year section {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 2.2em;
}
#timeline section.year section h4 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 89px;
  color: #C5C5C5;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  #timeline section.year section h4 {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
#timeline section.year section ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 75px;
  margin: -1.35rem 0 1em;
  max-width: 32rem;
  font-size: 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  #timeline section.year section ul {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 0 0 0 81px;
  }
}
#timeline section.year section ul:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#timeline section.year section ul:first-of-type:after {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #C5C5C5;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 54px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#timeline section.year section ul li {
  margin-left: .5rem;
}
#timeline section.year section ul li:before {
  content: '·';
  margin-left: -.5rem;
  padding-right: .3rem;
}
#timeline section.year section ul li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: .5rem;
}
#timeline section.year section ul li span.price {
  color: mediumturquoise;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#price {
  display: inline;
}

svg {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bitcoin timeline with fixed header using flexbox</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->

<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <div id="timeline">
      <div>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2007</h3>
          <section>
            <ul>
              <li>Satoshi Nakamoto began working on the Bitcoin concept.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>     
        </section>
  
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2008</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Neal Kin, Vladimir Oksman, and Charles Bry file an application for an encryption patent application.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin.org was registered at <a href="https://anonymousspeech.com/">anonymousspeech.com</a>.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
    
          <section>
            <h4>October</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Nakamoto describes the Bitcoin currency and solves the problem of double spending.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
    
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>The Bitcoin project is registered on <a href="https://sourceforge.net/">SourceForge.net</a>.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
  
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2009</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Block 0 is established.</li>
              <li>Version 0.1 of Bitcoin is released.</li>
              <li>The first Bitcoin transaction.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>October</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>An exchange rate is established.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.2 is released.</li>
              <li>The difficulty increases.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
  
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2010</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>The Bitcoin Market is established as a Bitcoin currency exchange.</li>
              <li>Encryption patent is published.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>May</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>The first real-world transaction using 10,000 BTC spent on pizza.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>July</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.3 released.</li>
              <li>In five days, the price grew 1000%, rising from <span class="price">$0.008</span> to  <span class="price">$0.08</span> for 1 bitcoin.</li>
              <li>The MtGox Bitcoin currency exchange market is established.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Exploit generates 184 billion Bitcoins.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>October</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Financial task force issues warning.</li>
              <li>The first public version of an OpenCL miner is released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Market cap exceeds $1 million USD.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoind compiled for Nokia N900.</li>
              <li>First mobile Bitcoin transaction.</li>
              <li>Difficulty increases.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2011</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Silk Road opens for business.</li>
              <li>25% of total Bitcoins generated.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin reaches parity with US dollar.</li>
              <li><a href="https://weusecoins.com/">WeUseCoins.com</a> is created.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Second largest decrease in difficulty.</li>
              <li>Britcoin opens for trading.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin Brasil opens.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>April</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin passes parity with Euro.</li>
              <li>Difficulty surpasses 100,000.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>June</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin Market drops PayPal.</li>
              <li>The largest percentage price decrease to-date became known as the Great Bubble of 2011. Top of bubble at <span class="price">$31.</span></li>
              <li>WikiLeaks starts accepting Bitcoin.</li>
              <li>Major breach of security at MtGox.</li>
              <li>Difficulty passes 1 million.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin Conference and World Expo in New York City, NY.</li>
              <li>P2Pool mines its first block.</li>
              <li>Back-to-back drop in difficulty.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>September</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Casascius coins mint physical Bitcoins.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin & Future Technology European Conference in Prague, Czech Republic.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><span class="price">$2</span> minimum price after the first price drop.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2012</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>September</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>London 2012 Bitcoin Conference.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin Foundation begins.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Slowly rising for a year. Price at <span class="price">$13.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2013</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.8 released.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin goes up to <span class="price">$30.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin spikes to $74.90.</li>
              <li>Market cap reaches $1 billion.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>April</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin surpasses <span class="price">$100.</span></li>
              <li>Price hits an all-time high of <span class="price">$266.</span></li>
              <li>Bitcoin Central is hacked.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>May</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>First Bitcoin ATM unveiled.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin Central gets hacked again.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>October</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>FBI shuts down Silk Road.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin price drops from <span class="price">$139</span> to <span class="price">$109.71</span> in less than three hours after Silk Road closure, recovers.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin price surges to a new all-time record of <span class="price">$1242.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Price crashed to <span class="price">$600</span>, rebounded to <span class="price">$1000</span>, crashed again to the <span class="price">$500</span> range. Stabilized in between.</li>
              <li>China's Central Bank bans Bitcoin transactions.</li>
              <li>The network exceeded 10 petahash/sec.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2014</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Price spiked to <span class="price">$1000</span>, then settled in the <span class="price">$800–$900</span>range.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.9 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>June</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>The network exceeded 100 petahash/sec.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Microsoft began to accept bitcoin to buy Xbox games and Windows apps.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2015</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.10 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>July</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.11 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>2015 record high of <span class="price">$504.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2016</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Price at <span class="price">$1150</span> per bitcoin.</li>
              <li>Price fell 30% in a week, reaching a multi-month low of <span class="price">$750.</span></li>
              <li>The network exceeded 1 exahash/sec.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.12 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>April</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Steam started accepting bitcoin as payment.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.13 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>September</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>There are 770 bitcoin ATMs worldwide.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2017</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.14 released.</li>
              <li>The price of 1 bitcoin surpassed the spot price of an ounce of gold for the first time.</li>
              <li>The number of GitHub projects related to bitcoin passed 10,000.</li>
              <li>Price traded above <span class="price">$1290.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>April</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Japan Declares Bitcoin as Legel Tender</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin "splits" into Bitcoin (BTC) and Bitcoin Cash (BCH)</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin for the first time hit <span class="price">$10,000</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2019</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>Today</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>At the moment, one bitcoin cost:
                <span class="price">
                  <div id="price"></div>.
                </span>
               </li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script >
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Learning I checked on setTimeout 0 it looks smooth. Maybe if you have. bigger dynamic timeline you can test it for performance.

Comment: I tried your query, it doesnt work and show syntax issue at this line `  const timelines = [...document.querySelectorAll('section.year > h3')]; // work on a detached list`

Comment: which browser ?

Comment: @Learning, can you check now.  Anyhow i updated to ES5 syntax

Comment: Not sure why itsnt working on my system, i will mark your answer as correct as its working here and serves the purpose. I will sort it out may be some small mistak on my part in code..

Comment: `var timelines = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('section.year > h3'));//ES5`: `Array.from()` is definitely ES6, and completely unneeded here...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a CSS only idea with `mix-blend-mode` where the trick is to have a pseudo element with background coloration that is below the sticky element covering all the space. When the element will start its sticky behavior, it will be above that area and the coloration will change.

Relevant code

```
#timeline section.year {
  position:relative;
  background:#fff;
}

#timeline section.year:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    bottom: 1em;
    background: red;
    z-index: 2;
    mix-blend-mode: color;
}
```

Full code

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:200,400,500);
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #79838c;
}

a {
  color: #50585f;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #383e44;
}

div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100%;
}

div.header {
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: slategrey;
  color: ghostwhite;
  padding: 2.3rem 1rem 2.3rem 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
div.header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5rem;
  left: 0rem;
  height: 5.1rem;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 300;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, white 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 );
  /* IE6-9 */
}
div.header h1 {
  margin-top: .8rem;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  div.header h1 {
    font-size: 1.9em;
    letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
  }
}
div.header h2 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #cfd7de;
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: auto;
}

div.item {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0rem 1rem 0rem 1rem;

}

#timeline {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 5rem;

}
#timeline div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: .5rem;
  bottom: 0rem;
  left: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #C5C5C5;
}
#timeline h3 {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 5rem;
  color: #888;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  #timeline h3 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
}
#timeline section.year {
  position: relative;
}
#timeline section.year:first-child section {
  margin-top: -1.3em;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#timeline section.year section {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 2.2em;
}
#timeline section.year section h4 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 89px;
  color: #C5C5C5;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  #timeline section.year section h4 {
    font-size: 1em;
  }
}
#timeline section.year section ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 75px;
  margin: -1.35rem 0 1em;
  max-width: 32rem;
  font-size: 1em;
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  #timeline section.year section ul {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 0 0 0 81px;
  }
}
#timeline section.year section ul:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#timeline section.year section ul:first-of-type:after {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #C5C5C5;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 54px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#timeline section.year section ul li {
  margin-left: .5rem;
}
#timeline section.year section ul li:before {
  content: '·';
  margin-left: -.5rem;
  padding-right: .3rem;
}
#timeline section.year section ul li:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: .5rem;
}
#timeline section.year section ul li span.price {
  color: mediumturquoise;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#price {
  display: inline;
}

svg {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.11), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

#timeline section.year {
  position:relative;
  background:#fff;
}

#timeline section.year:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    bottom: 1em;
    background: red;
    z-index: 2;
    mix-blend-mode: color;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bitcoin timeline with fixed header using flexbox</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->

<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <div id="timeline">
      <div>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2007</h3>
          <section>
            <ul>
              <li>Satoshi Nakamoto began working on the Bitcoin concept.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>     
        </section>
  
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2008</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Neal Kin, Vladimir Oksman, and Charles Bry file an application for an encryption patent application.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin.org was registered at <a href="https://anonymousspeech.com/">anonymousspeech.com</a>.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
    
          <section>
            <h4>October</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Nakamoto describes the Bitcoin currency and solves the problem of double spending.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
    
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>The Bitcoin project is registered on <a href="https://sourceforge.net/">SourceForge.net</a>.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
  
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2009</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Block 0 is established.</li>
              <li>Version 0.1 of Bitcoin is released.</li>
              <li>The first Bitcoin transaction.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>October</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>An exchange rate is established.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.2 is released.</li>
              <li>The difficulty increases.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
  
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2010</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>The Bitcoin Market is established as a Bitcoin currency exchange.</li>
              <li>Encryption patent is published.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>May</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>The first real-world transaction using 10,000 BTC spent on pizza.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>July</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.3 released.</li>
              <li>In five days, the price grew 1000%, rising from <span class="price">$0.008</span> to  <span class="price">$0.08</span> for 1 bitcoin.</li>
              <li>The MtGox Bitcoin currency exchange market is established.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Exploit generates 184 billion Bitcoins.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>October</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Financial task force issues warning.</li>
              <li>The first public version of an OpenCL miner is released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Market cap exceeds $1 million USD.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoind compiled for Nokia N900.</li>
              <li>First mobile Bitcoin transaction.</li>
              <li>Difficulty increases.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2011</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Silk Road opens for business.</li>
              <li>25% of total Bitcoins generated.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin reaches parity with US dollar.</li>
              <li><a href="https://weusecoins.com/">WeUseCoins.com</a> is created.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Second largest decrease in difficulty.</li>
              <li>Britcoin opens for trading.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin Brasil opens.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>April</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin passes parity with Euro.</li>
              <li>Difficulty surpasses 100,000.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>June</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin Market drops PayPal.</li>
              <li>The largest percentage price decrease to-date became known as the Great Bubble of 2011. Top of bubble at <span class="price">$31.</span></li>
              <li>WikiLeaks starts accepting Bitcoin.</li>
              <li>Major breach of security at MtGox.</li>
              <li>Difficulty passes 1 million.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin Conference and World Expo in New York City, NY.</li>
              <li>P2Pool mines its first block.</li>
              <li>Back-to-back drop in difficulty.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>September</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Casascius coins mint physical Bitcoins.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin & Future Technology European Conference in Prague, Czech Republic.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li><span class="price">$2</span> minimum price after the first price drop.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2012</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>September</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>London 2012 Bitcoin Conference.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin Foundation begins.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Slowly rising for a year. Price at <span class="price">$13.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2013</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.8 released.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin goes up to <span class="price">$30.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin spikes to $74.90.</li>
              <li>Market cap reaches $1 billion.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>April</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin surpasses <span class="price">$100.</span></li>
              <li>Price hits an all-time high of <span class="price">$266.</span></li>
              <li>Bitcoin Central is hacked.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>May</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>First Bitcoin ATM unveiled.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin Central gets hacked again.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>October</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>FBI shuts down Silk Road.</li>
              <li>Bitcoin price drops from <span class="price">$139</span> to <span class="price">$109.71</span> in less than three hours after Silk Road closure, recovers.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin price surges to a new all-time record of <span class="price">$1242.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Price crashed to <span class="price">$600</span>, rebounded to <span class="price">$1000</span>, crashed again to the <span class="price">$500</span> range. Stabilized in between.</li>
              <li>China's Central Bank bans Bitcoin transactions.</li>
              <li>The network exceeded 10 petahash/sec.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2014</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Price spiked to <span class="price">$1000</span>, then settled in the <span class="price">$800–$900</span>range.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.9 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>June</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>The network exceeded 100 petahash/sec.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>December</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Microsoft began to accept bitcoin to buy Xbox games and Windows apps.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2015</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.10 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>July</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.11 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>2015 record high of <span class="price">$504.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2016</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Price at <span class="price">$1150</span> per bitcoin.</li>
              <li>Price fell 30% in a week, reaching a multi-month low of <span class="price">$750.</span></li>
              <li>The network exceeded 1 exahash/sec.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.12 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>April</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Steam started accepting bitcoin as payment.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.13 released.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>September</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>There are 770 bitcoin ATMs worldwide.</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2017</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Version 0.14 released.</li>
              <li>The price of 1 bitcoin surpassed the spot price of an ounce of gold for the first time.</li>
              <li>The number of GitHub projects related to bitcoin passed 10,000.</li>
              <li>Price traded above <span class="price">$1290.</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>April</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Japan Declares Bitcoin as Legel Tender</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>August</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin "splits" into Bitcoin (BTC) and Bitcoin Cash (BCH)</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h4>November</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>Bitcoin for the first time hit <span class="price">$10,000</span></li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
        <section class="year">
          <h3>2019</h3>
          <section>
            <h4>Today</h4>
            <ul>
              <li>At the moment, one bitcoin cost:
                <span class="price">
                  <div id="price"></div>.
                </span>
               </li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script >
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Vucko no it's quite good if we omit dead browsers of course: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Quite nice! "dead browsers" - and there's still me in 2019. needing to provide IE10 support.